# Удалять элемент из массива при удалении o.$delete() элемента $resource

Tags: angularjs, crud

AngularJS 1.6.x

В контроллере пишу:

```
var Vehicle = $resource(prfx+'vehicles/:Id', {Id:'@id'});
var vehicles = Vehicle.query(
    function(){
      $scope.list = vehicles;
      $scope.selected = [vehicles[vehicles.length-1]];
    }
  );
```

Выбор элемента для редактирования сделал так:

```
<select ng-model="selected">

  <option ng-repeat="option in list  | orderBy:'id' track by option.id" ng-value="option">
    #{{option.id}} {{option.title}}</option>

</select>
```

В шаблоне хочется написать простые кнопки

```
<form ng-repeat="option in selected " ng-submit="option.$save()" >
    формочки
    <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="option.$delete()">Удалить</button>
</form>
```

Метод DELETE исполняется на сервере и вроде бы ресурс можно удалить из модели. Но он не удаляется сам.

Мне необходимо добавлять свой обработчик удаления или можно вызвать этот метод так чтоб всё сработало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так просто не получится, так как операции над отдельным объектом никак не влияют на список в котором он находится.

Для решения стоит завести функцию, принимающую конкретную опцию, и в этой функции при успешном завершении `$delete` можно удалять опцию из списка.

Например так:

```
$scope.removeOption = function removeOption(list,option){
    option.$delete(function success(){
        // удаление объекта option из нужного списка
    });
}
```

и вызов в разметке

```
<button type="button" ng-click="removeOption(list,option)">Удалить</button>
```

Comment: @eri, вообще передавать список не обязательно, в большинстве случаев он будет доступен через `$scope`, в отличие от выбранного `option`

Comment: я вынес эту функцию в отдельную фабрику. там нет скопа. В эту же фабрику положу все типовые операции со списком

Comment: @eri, в ответе специально не указано как именно удалять из списка. Вариантов удаления может быть несколько, плюс в списке может отсутствовать выбранный option, поэтому не стоит дописывать конкретную реализацию. Кроме того, `success` написано умышленно, так как этот коллбэк именно для успешного завершения функции `$delete`

Comment: слово "Например" просило меня дополнить пример.)

Comment: @eri, тут просто пример _функции в которой все происходит_ и пример того, что в `$delete` можно передавать коллбэки, вторый параметром можно так же передать обработчик для ошибочного завершения.